# Resolve promise.all inside a useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple useEffect in my component to fetch data from 3 API calls:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=color`),
      fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=brand`),
      fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=category`)
    ]).then(([x, y, z])=> {
        console.log(x.json(), y.json(), z.json());
      });
  }, []);
```

I'm expecting the actual data I get from the API so that I can use it in my UI, but instead I'm getting this:
[image]

I've also tried doing this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=color`),
      fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=brand`),
      fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=category`)
    ]).then(responses => responses.map(r => r.json()))
      .then(([x, y, z])=> {
        console.log(x, y, z);
      });
  }, []);
```

I see the desired value inside `PromiseResult`, but I'm not sure how to extract it:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here. How do I access the array in my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I think you already understand at least a little about handling asynchronous code with Promises, but you seem to not be realising that the `json` method on a `fetch` result *itself* returns a Promise. In your case the simplest solution is probably to change `responses => responses.map(r => r.json())` to `responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json()))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `.json` returns another promise, so you'd need to call `.then` on it to get the eventual value. Or since you're doing multiple, you'd need to combine it with `Promise.all`, and then call `.then` on that.

One possibility is to tweak your `.map` attempt so that it has an additional `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all([
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=color`),
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=brand`),
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=category`)
]).then(responses => {
  return Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json()))
})
.then(([x, y, z])=> {
  console.log(x, y, z);
});
```

But that does have the downside that *all* of the fetches must get far enough along that they resolve, before *any* of them can call `.json`. This may slightly delay finishing things. So another possibility is to set up all of the work up front, and only call `Promise.all` with those final promises.

```
Promise.all([
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=color`).then(val => val.json()),
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=brand`).then(val => val.json()),
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=category`.then(val => val.json()))
]).then(([x, y, z])=> {
  console.log(x, y, z);
});
```

With that version, each of the fetches will go at whatever pace it can manage, and will convert itself to json as soon as it can. Then once all of them are finished, the combined promise resolves.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine your all fetch call and `map()` to generate an array of promises to easily loop the data:

```js
const baseUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

  useEffect(() => {
    const urls = [`${baseUrl}/todos/1`, `${baseUrl}/todos/2`, `${baseUrl}/todos/3`];

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const responses = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)));
        const data = await Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json()));
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `await` instead of `then`, this is how I would refactor your code:

```js
useEffect(async () =>
  console.log(...await Promise.all(
    ['color','brand','category']
      .map(async i => (await fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=${i}`)).json())))
, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a `getByEntity` function that wraps a single fetch operation, then mao over the list of entities that you need to retrieve:

```js
const baseUrl = '...';

// outside of your component
async function getByEntity(entity) {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/counts?entity=${entity}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

// inside your component
useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all(
    ['color', 'brand', 'category'].map(getByEntity)
  ).then(([x, y, z])=> {
    console.log(x, y, z);
  });
}, []);
```